# Notifications with service and receiver

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-broadcast, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to make notification in my application.

The receiver must open the notification service if the device restarted
but it doesn't work.

Here is my code >>

Service code

```
public class MyService extends Service {

String myringtone;
long[] myviber;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Intent intent1 =new Intent(this,MyService.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle=intent.getExtras();
    myviber=bundle.getLongArray("veberationdata");
    myringtone=bundle.getString("ringtonedata");

    intent1.putExtra("ringtonedata", myringtone);
    intent1.putExtra("veberationdata", myviber);

    AlarmManager manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1= PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent1, 0);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000,0,pendingIntent1);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    //     notification.setAutoCancel(true);
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.war_pic_white);
    long[] viber_no=new long[]{100, 200, 100, 500};
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String savedringtone = sharedPreferences.getString("ringtonefornoti", null);
    Uri ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(savedringtone);

    notification.setTicker(".......M E S S E G.......");
    notification.setContentTitle("Title of noti");
    notification.setContentText("summary ");
    notification.setSound(ringtoneUri);
    notification.setVibrate(viber_no);

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MyService.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    long time = new Date().getTime();
    String tmpStr = String.valueOf(time);
    String last4Str = tmpStr.substring(tmpStr.length() - 5);
    int notificationId = Integer.valueOf(last4Str);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notification.build());
    return START_STICKY;

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

my receiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle = intent.getExtras();

    String mystate = bundle.getString("state");

    if (mystate.equals("ON")) {

        Intent serviceintent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(serviceintent);
    }
    else if (mystate.equals("OFF"))
    {
        Intent serviceintent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.stopService(serviceintent);
    }
}
```

}

my setting activity

```
public class SettingPage extends PreferenceActivity {

        boolean viber_sw_on_off,notifi_sw_on_off;
        int savedhour , savedmint , savedviber;
        long[] viber_no;
        String savedringtone, typeofnotify;

        SwitchPreference notifi_switch, viber_switch;
        ListPreference list_pref;
        Preference time_pref;
        RingtonePreference ring_pref;

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences ,savedpref;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.mypref);

    sharedPreferences  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    notifi_switch = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("notifications_switch");
    viber_switch  = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("vibrate_switch");
    list_pref     = (ListPreference) findPreference("list_ofnotify");
    time_pref     = (Preference) findPreference("time_pre");
    ring_pref     = (RingtonePreference) findPreference("ringtonefornoti");

    savedpref= getSharedPreferences("MySetting", MODE_PRIVATE);
    savedhour = savedpref.getInt("phour", 0);
    savedmint = savedpref.getInt("pmint", 0);
    savedringtone = savedpref.getString("mring",null);
    savedviber = savedpref.getInt("mveb",1);


    if (savedhour != 0)
    {
        time_pref.setSummary(savedhour + ":" + savedmint);
    }

    if (savedringtone == null)
    {
        savedringtone =(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI.getPath());
    }

    if (savedviber == 0)
    {
        viber_no=new long[]{0};

    }
    else
    {
        viber_no=new long[]{100, 200, 100, 500};
    }






    notifi_switch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

            setNotification();
            return true;
        }
    });

    list_pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

            setnotify();
            return true;
        }
    });

    time_pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            setTime_pref();
            return true;
        }
    });


    viber_switch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

            setViberation();
            return true;
        }
    });

    ring_pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

            setring();
            return true;
        }
    }); 
}




public void setTime_pref() {

    Calendar c  = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int mHour   = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {
                    time_pref.setSummary(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

                    SharedPreferences Mytime = getSharedPreferences("MySetting",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Mytime.edit();
                    editor.putInt("phour",mHour);
                    editor.putInt("pmint",mMinute);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    tpd.show();
}


public void setNotification()
{
    notifi_sw_on_off = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("notifications_switch", true);

    MyReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();

    if (notifi_sw_on_off == false)
    {


        Intent broadcastintent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyReceiver.class);

        broadcastintent.putExtra("state", "ON");

        sendBroadcast(broadcastintent);


        registerReceiver(myReceiver,new IntentFilter("com.example.pushups.MyReceiver"));

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        Intent serviceintent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);

        bundle.putString("ringtonedata",savedringtone);
        bundle.putLongArray("veberationdata", viber_no);
        serviceintent.putExtras(bundle);

        startService(serviceintent);

    }
    else if (notifi_sw_on_off == true)
    {

        Intent broadcastintent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyReceiver.class);

        broadcastintent.putExtra("state","OFF");

        sendBroadcast(broadcastintent);

        Intent serviceintent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);
        stopService(serviceintent);

        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);


    }
}


public void setring()
{

    String savedringtone = sharedPreferences.getString("ringtonefornoti", null);


    SharedPreferences myringtone = getSharedPreferences("MySetting",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myringtone.edit();
    editor.putString("mring", savedringtone);
    editor.commit();

}

public void setViberation()
{
    viber_sw_on_off  = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("vibrate_switch", false);

    if (viber_sw_on_off == false)
    {
        viber_no=new long[]{100, 200, 100, 500};


        SharedPreferences myviberation = getSharedPreferences("MySetting",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myviberation.edit();
        editor.putInt("mveb", 1);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else if(viber_sw_on_off == true)
    {
        viber_no=new long[]{0};

        SharedPreferences myviberation = getSharedPreferences("MySetting",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myviberation.edit();
        editor.putInt("mveb", 0);
        editor.commit();
    }

}


public void setnotify()
{
    typeofnotify = sharedPreferences.getString("list_pref","Defult_Value");

    String s = list_pref.getEntry().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (typeofnotify.equals(""))
    {

    }

}

}
```

my manifest

```
        <service
        android:name=".MyService">
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.pushups.MyReceiver"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

[hehe an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwdTW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check the followings

1. Set a log.v onReceive in MyReceiver.class for receive works or not.
2. if it works, Set a log.v to know the value of "mystate" 
   (Sometimes sharedPreferences values doesn't saved properly)
3. then if it works, Check the Intent of Startservice. 
   (Sometimes Intent didnt work due to Context Problem)

4.if the service starts properly, check the Notification Manager Correctly.

5.Uninstall the Unwanted third-Party Application.

Note:

Best Solution to start & stop service to avoid Context problems:

1. `startService(new Intent(YourActivity.this, MyService.class));`
2. `stopService(new Intent(YourActivity.this, MyService.class));`